# Appending Multiple Rows Of Pandas DataFrame into New DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a current data frame as below :

```
   F1 , F2 , F3 , F4 , Label
   1  , 2  , 3  , 4  ,  Dog 
   2  , 3  , 4  , 5  ,  Cat
   3  , 4  , 5  , 6  ,  Cat
   4  , 5  , 6  , 7  ,  Dog 
   5  , 6  , 7  , 8  ,  Cat
   6  , 7  , 8  , 9  ,  Dog

               .
               . 
               . 
               . 

   1  , 2  , 3  , 4  ,  Dog
```

What I want is to iterate over the dataframe and combine next 3 rows into one row and then right to another dataframe so that I have the following output :

```
   F1 , F2 , F3 , F4 , Label , F1 , F2 , F3 , F4 , Label , F1 , F2 , F3 , F4 , Label
   1  , 2  , 3  , 4  ,  Dog  , 2  , 3  , 4  , 5  , Cat   , 3  , 4  , 5  , 6  ,  Cat
   2  , 3  , 4  , 5  ,  Cat  , 3  , 4  , 5  , 6  , Cat   , 4  , 5  , 6  , 7  ,  Dog
   3  , 4  , 5  , 6  ,  Cat  , 4  , 5  , 6  , 7  , Dog   , 5  , 6  , 7  , 8  ,  Cat
   4  , 5  , 6  , 7  ,  Dog  , 5  , 6  , 7  , 8  , Cat   , 6  , 7  , 8  , 9  ,  Dog
```

I know that the last 2 rows will not have NaN values but that doesnt matter as I can always drop them later.

The code I have is as below :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


path = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Research Paper\Training and Validation.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path)
cols = ['Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label',
        'Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label',
        'Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label',
        'Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label',
        'Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label',
        'Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label',
        'Positive Score','Compound Score','Negative Score','Neutral Score','Class Label']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)


rows = []

for index, row in df.items() :
    row_m = df.iloc[index:index+6]
    rows.append(row_m)

new_df = pd.concat(rows,axis=1)

print(new_df)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your code not give the expected result? What you obtain instead?

Comment: It gives me a an error 'TypeError: must be str, not int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
subdf = [df.iloc[i:i+len(df)-2].reset_index(drop=True) for i in range(3)]
ddf = pd.concat(subdf, axis=1)
print(ddf)
```

If `df` is the dataframe you gave as an example (I dropped the comma separator and the last line) the above code prints:

```
   F1  F2  F3  F4 Label  F1  F2  F3  F4 Label  F1  F2  F3  F4 Label
0   1   2   3   4   Dog   2   3   4   5   Cat   3   4   5   6   Cat
1   2   3   4   5   Cat   3   4   5   6   Cat   4   5   6   7   Dog
2   3   4   5   6   Cat   4   5   6   7   Dog   5   6   7   8   Cat
3   4   5   6   7   Dog   5   6   7   8   Cat   6   7   8   9   Dog
```

And no need to drop `NaN` values if you stop the selection at the correct line (that's the purpose of `-2` in `i+len(df)-2`).
Note also the use of `reset.index(drop=True)`: the sliced dataframes need to  forget about their original indexes otherwise `pd.concat` later will attach each row at its original index. `drop=True` prevents from adding a column `index` holding the original indexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. On side note, if I want to increase the number of rows to append from 3 to 7 (or something else), all I need to do is to change `for i in range(3)` to `for i in range(7)` or do I have to to something else to achieve the same results?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly. Nothing more, just fix: `i+len(df)-2` to `i+len(df)-6` to avoid the last rows with `Nan`.

Comment: Difficult to answer without looking at the data. Number of columns or rows should not matter, provided that you have enough rows. Be sure that `i+len(df)-6` (or whatever number you subtract) is not a negative number. If this is the case, make it non negative, but you will get some `Nan` values in every row.

Comment: I deleted the comment because the code works fine, the problem was with Visual Studio which was not reading the data correctly from the csv file. A restart of the application solved the problem. Cheers and thanks once again